# Angular2 - Can display Object, Properties wont Display

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-template

I've been trying to Learn Angular / NodeJS and have been doing alright so far, however I've hit a snag that I just can't seem to get past.

So I'm using Node to run API calls, using and Angular Service to pass the response to the component and the rendering it in the view (I'm pretty new to all this so my terminology may be off apologies)!

I managed to do this successfully using: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

However I replicated it using RIOT API as I'd like to use something more personal to me to learn.

Component:

```
export class SummonerComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Summoner Search';

  summoner: any = [];

  constructor(private summonerService: SummonerService) { }

 ngOnInit() {

   this.summonerService.getSummoner().subscribe(summoner => {
     this.summoner = summoner;
   });

  }
}
```

API Call:

```
router.get('/summoner/', (req, res) => {
  rp({
    uri: 'https://euw.api.riotgames.com/api/lol/EUW/v1.4/summoner/by-name/MYSUMMONERNAME',
    qs: {

    },
    headers: {
        MY HEADERS         
    },
    json: true
  })
  .then((data)=> {
    res.status(200).json(data);
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.status(500).send(error)
  });
```

})

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SummonerService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getSummoner(){
    return this.http.get('/get/summoner')
    .map(res => res.json());
  } 

}
```

HTML:

```
<h2> {{ summoner.name }} </h2>
<p>
  {{ summoner }}
</p>
<p>
  summoner works!
</p>
```

Within my HTML {{ summoner }} displays [Object][Object] adding the JSON Pipe e.g. {{ summoner | json }} I see the actual data returned from the Call (YAY)

However the {{ summoner.name }} does not render in the view. I do not get an error, it just doesn't load the property?

The data returned is structured as follows:

```
{"MYSUMMONERNAME":{"id":MYID,"name":"MYSUMMONERNAME","profileIconId":"ICONID","revisionDate":"REVISIONDATE","summonerLevel":"MYLEVEL"}}
```

None of the properties will display, e.g. {{ summoner.summonerLevel }} etc

Its probably something small, but I just cant get it to render.

Thanks

Comment: {{ summoner.MYSUMMONERNAME.name }}

Comment: I'd added "MYSUMMONERNAME" in place of the actual name returned from the call to keep my privacy. What would I put in place of that?

Answer (score 0):

Change it as,

```
this.summonerService.getSummoner().subscribe(summoner => {
     this.summoner = summoner.MYSUMMONERNAME;
});
```

Comment: This has now caused an error, it cannot read the property of undefined. I was getting no error originally, it just wouldn't render the property on the page. Thanks though!

Comment: do this on your template <h2> {{ summoner?.name }} </h2>

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I had already tried that also but still, the property will not render on the page.

Comment: I just simply cannot get the property to render, rendering {{ summoner | json }} I see all the info, but trying to use just {{ summoner.name }} for example, does not render anything, just a blank space.

Comment: See: http://imgur.com/JPie6K0 - Its fine when I use {{ summoner | json }} (displayed fine as in screenshot) but accessing the "Name" etc I just cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Change the service method to

```
//In your service
getSummoner(){
    return this.http.get('/get/summoner')
    .map(res => res.json()[0]);
  } 

//In your component
summoner: any;//summoner is not an array, is a POJO

//In your template
<ng-container *ngIf="summoner">
  //here your current template
</ng-container>
```

And as suggestion, define an interface with the return data of your HTTP request

UPDATE: personal suggestion to your comment

Asumming that you give the username as parameter to your service method and you expect a single entry result:

```
getSummoner(summonerId: string){
    return this.http.get(`/get/summoner/${summonerId}`)
    .map(res => res.json().[summonerId]);
  }
```

Somehow you will need to catch/parse/retrieve this route parameter value in your backend, but I cant tell you how cause I have 0 experience with express :D

Comment: Hey thanks for helping :) , I tried this, now I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". <p> {{ summoner.name }} </p> is what I'm using? - PS - Interface was the next thing on my list, I just want to figure this out first.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps

Comment: I really appreciate your time, it still isn't displaying anything. This is really irritating me now. How can I do it with the Posts Placeholder (linked above) but this simple one isn't working.

Comment: The problem is most likely related to the json()[0], I thought it was possible to access the properties of a POJO by index, but after further looking I think is not possible. If its not a problem for you, you could try by replacing the 0 with the summonername value or try to return from your backend the nested object contained in the summonername property and then change the service method to only res.json()

Comment: Hello, the great news is replacing the  [0] on the json()[0] did populate the data on the page HURRAH. However, I was hoping to allow myself to search a summoner name, how could I get this to work through a parameter?

Comment: Updated my answer, but your next question is out of the scope of this one though

Comment: Hopefully this may help someone in future, I managed to resolve this myself. As you say, the object returned was a POJO. It was my understanding the HTTP Client I was using returned the object as JSON by default. After a bit of tinkering I managed to get it returned as a valid JSON object and successfully displayed the properties. Much appreciated for your time :)